# Change position of an absolutely positioned element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have two elements, one on the top of another. I want to change position of the absolutely positioned element on button click.

jQuery:

```
$("#check-button").click(function() {
    $("#repair-status").animate({top: "80"}, 1000);
});
```

It seems pretty easy, but it doesn't work in this case. I guess, something is wrong with the CSS. For more details look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamsvyat/93A9f/9/

Thanks in advance!

P.S. for clarity i put the "repair-status" element on top, in final it would slide from bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/93A9f/10/

```
$("#check-button").click(function() {
    $("#repair-status").animate({top: "80"}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

All i did was add `return false;` to cancel the default action of a postback on the button click.

Comment: I would recommend using `e.preventDefault()` (and accepting the event parameter) instead of `return false;` so you don't prevent bubbling and potentially break event delegation. http://jsfiddle.net/iamsvyat/93A9f/9/

Comment: @jbabey, thanks, that solves my problem. Also, the fiddle in your comment is broken. I assume, you wanted to post the working one :)

Comment: @SvyatoslavSykalo helps if you click the update button first... http://jsfiddle.net/93A9f/12/

Comment: @jbabey, yeap, the 9th version of fiddle is without e.preventDefault() and the 12th version is with it.